# How to configure WebStorm to properly format generator functions?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, eslint

I'm using WebStorm code auto formatting and notice that it doesn't format correctly generator functions. I need this:

```
function* (), function* name()
```

But WebStorm formats it to this:

```
function*(), function* name()
```

There are some settings in WebStorm's code style preferences, but seems like they do not cover this case. Are there any solutions?

Comment: WebStorm doesn't have any code style options for generator functions, here's a related feature request that you can follow for updates: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20668

Comment: @EkaterinaPrigara cool, thanks a lot, will follow it!

Answer (score 1):

Webstorm does not seem to have this option (my Webstorm 2016.1.2 ignores generator function when formating).
A workaround for this problem is a grunt / gulp task that rewrites the files (do a backup first!). So you would use a plugin like [gulp-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace) to define a task `gulp reformat` that you call after formatting with Webstorm.
Not the best solution, but it should work ;)
However, I would wait for an update.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However I was thinking there are probably some native ways to change formatting rules, like changing some .idea files or something like that. But anyway we have at least your solution